# An error: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG in project with MSTSCLib

Tags: c#, com, activex, regsvr32

I need to fix a project that uses rdp ActiveX component. The error states:

```
HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)
```

It raises near this code:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.rdpClientControl);
```

where rdpClientControl is:

```
this.rdpClientControl = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
```

There also two dll files come in with this project 
**Interop.MSTSCLib.dll** and **AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll**
I understand that I must register this component in my system, but which file I must register (tried to use regsvr32 with both of them but it failed).
Also I've got strange message from intellisense in my code: that this line is not supported by my language.

```
rdpClientControl.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
```

Never encountered an errors like this before, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is in `msrdp.ocx`.
To register ActiveX run: `Regsvr32 msrdp.ocx`